# Pattern matching in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, scripting

I need help with pattern matching. I have the following text as the output of a command.

```
 j-13PUDS1BDAAKK     RUNNING        ec2-54-242-150-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com        Log    Processing Job Flow   
  COMPLETED      Setup Hive
  RUNNING        CopyLogs
  PENDING        CopyLogs
  PENDING        CopyLogs
  PENDING        CopyLogs
```

I need to match the CopyLogs output to Completed. So basically after the execution of the command the output should be

```
COMPLETED        CopyLogs
COMPLETED        CopyLogs
COMPLETED        CopyLogs
COMPLETED        CopyLogs
```

How do I do that in a do while loop (for a retry logic). I tried the following

```
while :; do
result=$(elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --list) //lets say this returns the above output
[[ $result == +(*RUNNING*|*PENDING*|*WAITING*) ]] || break
done
echo "result now has no RUNNING or PENDING or WAITING"
```

but I just need to do this for "CopyLogs". How do I achieve that

Comment: Curiously, the OP aleeady seems to have solved this, in a way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853440/syntax-error-in-shell-script-saying-unexpected-token

Answer (score 0):

```
result=$(elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --list|grep -P '(COMPLETED[[:space:]]*CopyLogs)')
```

`result` will carry the required output.

-P perl-regular expression, please check `man grep`