# Syntax error in shell script saying unexpected token `(

Tags: bash, shell

I have written the following shell script

```
while :; do
status=$($EMR_BIN/elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --list | grep "CopyLogs" | awk '{print $1}')
[[ $status == +( *RUNNING*|*PENDING*|*WAITING* ) ]] || break
sleep 60
done
```

Its giving me an error in line 3 saying  `syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token`('' . I tried giving whitespaces between my braces, but its not working.

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: You have to use "=~" operator instead of "==". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use extended globbing. Make sure you have `shopt -s extglob` somewhere earlier in your script, or rewrite to use standard globbing.

```
#!/bin/sh
while :; do
    case $($EMR_BIN/elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --list | awk '/CopyLogs/{print $1}') in
        *RUNNING*|*PENDING*|*WAITING* ) sleep 60;; 
        *) break;;
    esac
done
```

Since there are no remaining Bashisms, this script is now POSIX `sh` compatible. (Personally, I also think it is more readable this way.)

(Note also the fix for the useless `grep | awk`.)

Comment: oh ok you mean to say to use `shopt -x extglob` ,right?